# Display the contents of folders dynamically with chrome.fileSystem

Tags: html, filesystems, google-chrome-app

Is this possible with chrome.filesystem that clicking on the name of a folder displayed above list form, it dynamically displays the files in that folder. example:

Here are my issues:
folder 1
folder 2
folder 3

If I click on the folder 2, chrome displays me the files contained in the folder 2. And so on.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you looked at the filesystem-access sample? https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/filesystem-access

Comment: Yes I based on the example. And it works. But for a folder at a time. What I would like is to have a list of several folders and when I select the desired folder, I display the files in that folder. But for that, I have not found how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to answer this:

1. If the app has all of the info (the entire tree structure) already available to it, then the answer is yes, it is possible to construct such a dynamic UI.
2. If the app has to do #1, but in addition discover the files and directories in each directory, then the only way to list the contents of a directory is to have the user explicitly choose that directory with `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry`. Once a directory is chosen by the user, you can enumerate its contents recursively without the user having to make further choices with `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry`. For details of how to do the above (e.g., enumerate the contents), see the example referred to in the comment and also the details of the chrome.fileSystem APIs.

UPDATE: Once the user has chosen a file or directory with `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry`, the app can retain that entry with a call to `chrome.fileSystem.retainEntry` and. in a subsequent execution of the app, restore it with `chrome.fileSystem.restoreEntry`, thus obviating the need for the user to choose it again.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The way that I do it, the user will select a project, then another and another, ect. Once he select multiple projects, it can later click on one of its projects to display the contained dynamically. Right now, I can dynamically display the files in the folder selected last. But I'd like to do for others as well. I do not know if I'm clear :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Edited my answer; see above.

Comment: But is there a way for all projects to be stored in case the person wants to open an "old" project? Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate!

Comment: You can store all projects in a directory chosen once by the user during app setup. When that choice is made, retain that directory, and then you can create and access any number of directories and files within it without any further use of `chooseEntry`.